# WiFi bridge mode performance - regular slowdowns

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

I have a BT Home Hub plugged into the wall, and I have an Archer AC1750 connected to it in Wireless Bridge mode.

That is, the WAN port on the Archer isn't connected to anything, the Archer connects to the home hub over WiFi, and my desktop PC connects to the Archer over ethernet. I'm doing this because I have a couple of devices on my desk (IP phone, Ingenico card reader) that have to plug into ethernet, there's no possible way of running ethernet cable from my desk to the BT Home Hub, and the WiFI throughput is better this way than when I had a USB WiFI adapter plugged into the PC.

This normally works great:

[image: speedtest result]

but about once a day (on average) it slows down massively:

[image: ping stats]

(253 is the Archer, 254 is the home hub) and nothing really works until I reboot the Archer. Rebooting the router on my desk fixes the problem, so I don't think it's anything at the Home Hub end.

I don't like rebooting something once a day to work around an unexplained problem, so:

What could be causing this slowdown? What log files can I get to help me diagnose what triggers it? Could it be something to do with WiFi interference, channels, that sort of thing, or is it more likely to just be internal to the Archer?

UPDATE: I downloaded a free ping monitor tool (EMCO Ping Monitor Free) and recorded all the outages. CSV log is here: https://pastebin.com/7TZLDCs9

What was notable was: 
 1. We were away from 28th - 4th, and in that time there were no outages. My desktop machine remained online, syncing to Dropbox and SyncThing and I dialed into it a couple of times to do things, so there was traffic - but no outages. 
 2. Outage occurs in the night, and the network is up and down every 2 minutes for ~30 minutes before it resolves itself.

Which means that the cause of the problem must be a device that we took with us when we were away, that is normally switched on in the night. Which narrows it down to two mobile phones and a very old iPad.

I'm going to try switching the iPad off when not in use.

Comment: Once a day.... any specific time? Is there an event at that time of day that you could link to the network slowing down? Someone else's device on the network? One of your devices doing any updates or anything else? Anything backing up?

Comment: Good question. I'll keep a log, but I don't think it's exactly the same time. I once worked somewhere that routed an important ethernet cable through the kitchen, under the dishwasher... so everything always crashed just after lunch. 

And if it was external EM interference I wouldn't expect rebooting the router to fix it instantly.

Comment: It's inevitabyl not going to be EM interference... I'm thinking more along the lines of duplicate IP addresses or something is hammering your network (one of your devices, for example). Especially if you reboot the Archer and everything works... probably duplicate IP or something is heavy on the network.

Comment: I have updated the question with information about the times the outages occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inevitably, the solution was "Replace the BT Home Hub".

That has always been the answer to any weird behaviour I've had on a BT Internet connection, starting from the pre-launch trials in the late 90s. BT supplied kit is always worthless. I had thought the Home Hub 6 would be better, but whilst it does a tolerable job if you don't look at it too closely or ask too much of it, anything else and it lets you down.

A new Archer VR400 modem/router does WDS properly and works with the downstairs router just fine.